# Facebook php - post to Facebook fan page as an admin?

Tags: php, facebook

What is the best way to post to facebook fan page with php. I am the admin. I am using the php sdk. is it 100% safe to use publish stream. I am worried that facebook will ban my application.

is it safe to use this:

```
$facebook->api("/PAGE_ID/feed","POST",array("message"=>"Hello Page!"));
```

is there a better way to post ?

Comment: This isn't a question for StackOverflow. You can read Facebook's terms and agreements to find out.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need to create a FB app and give certain permissions to it. Then using this app, you can post to the Fan Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any problem in using it, unless you are trying to abuse their API system by sending toooo many requests. This is the best way to post/publish via PHP imo